# How do I name this anti-pattern

Tags: anti-patterns

I'm new at this company and looking at the code I see a lot of examples of this pattern

```
Class A
{ 

   object data;

   getData()
   {
      data = ...
   }

  processData()
  {
     //Process items in data
  }
}
```

So basically, the methods are exchanging data through fields of the class and are hiding what is happening inside them.
Ideally the calls should be like:

```
 data = getData();
 processData (data);
```

I need to talk to my manager about this repeating pattern in the code but I wonder if there's a name for it.